# Debug assertion failed during opencv imencode

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to encode a bmp image to jpg using `imencode` function of opencv (2.4.10) using the following code.

```
void test()
{
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("C:\\Users\\Maruf\\Pictures\\bingo.bmp", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    cv::vector<uchar> buf;
    cv::imencode(".jpg", img, buf); 
    return;
}
```

In `return` statement, the following exception is thrown. 
[image]

Why is this occurring and how can I fix this?

Comment: Code seems correct. The issuse seems to be in your configuration. Be sure to link to OpenCV debug libs in debug mode, while to release libs in release mode. Also check the OpenCV is built with the same compiler as your project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure the issue could be cause of using cross msvc version. Say, you are building the code with visual studio 10 and using the opencv dll & lib path of msvc 11 or msvc 12. Most of the cases it happens when we add the opencv directory in environment path. I found similar issue for blob detection where I was using visual studio 10 and using the opencv vc11 folder for lib & dll path. After changing it to vc10 it worked perfectly.

If you have opencv added in environment path, please change it and relaunch your visual studio. Also you need to make corresponding change to lib path of the project as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `cv::vector<uchar> buf;` to `std::vector<uchar> buf;`. The namespace `cv` doesn't have a `vector` object.

Comment: @qmaruf  Did you check that your bmp file existed ? I don't have a problem doing imencode on my side (OpenCV 3.1.0). Nor is there any issue on the return statement (Visual Studio 2013, Debug mode).

Comment: @gmaruf  Make sure you are using OpenCV debug libraries. Using the Release libraries in Debug mode can (and will almost always) lead to memory corruption errors like the one you get.

Answer (score 0):

Because of opencv linked as dynamic library, you need to sure to allocate and deallocate memory in the same heap address space.

buf - did allocate memory inside of cv::imencode (inside of opencv dll) but release when it out of the scope (in other heap space)

for instance in you example, you need allocate enought memory before put vector container into opencv function

    `cv::Mat img = cv::imread("C:\Users\Maruf\Pictures\bingo.bmp", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    //for instance allocate 10Mb.
    std::vector buf(10 * 1024 * 1024);
    cv::imencode(".jpg", img, buf);`